# How can I get integer output from a sql execution using F#

Tags: sql, f#

I am new in F#. So that I face some problem in my project.

```
let getTotalNoOfSmsPerDay (Db cStr) =
    use cmd = new SqlCommandProvider<"select COUNT(id) as NoOfSMS 
                                      from transport.SmsNotification 
                                      where CONVERT(date, CreatedOn) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
                                     ",ConnectionString, SingleRow = true>(cStr)
    async {
         let! result = cmd.AsyncExecute()
         return result
     }
```

This is my Code . I just want a integer number **NoOfSMS** . But It gives me `<Option<int>>`
How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Option` represents that nothing may be returned. This is the point where most other languages would return `null`.

There are a few ways to use the value inside `Option`. Explore the functions available.

Often what you will do though is to `match` on the 2 cases ie. `Some` value was returned or `None`.

```
match result with
| Some v -> v
| None -> 0
```

Here are some links to tutorials I have written on the topics.

[Control flow](https://devonburriss.me/how-to-fsharp-pt-4/)
[Pattern matching](https://devonburriss.me/how-to-fsharp-pt-5/)
[Handling no data](https://devonburriss.me/how-to-fsharp-pt-6/)

Comment: If I want to apply control flow statement in this result it doesn't work. like `let! noOfSMSPerday = connection.GetTotalNoOfSmsPerDay 
        if noOfSMSPerday <= 400 then  ` It gives error **Type mismatch :  'Async<string>' but given a  'Async<unit>'**

Comment: If you do not have an else, the return type is unit. Once you have got the int you might want to return from the async CE and just use the value. let n = async { return or return! } depending on what you working with.

Comment: You are right,As I don't write else it gives me unit . Thank you Solved it